# FlyingSaucer HTML to pdf image cutting and text rolling

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I'm forcing problem with converting dynamically html to pdf. Generated html is based on *ul* and *li* tags, there is also css file with styles. 
The problem is that when page ends, image gets cut and text is rolled into next from list. Has someone met problem like that? 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZuxI.png)

Is there any page break rule for flyingsauer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try out pdfHTML, get a trial license from itextpdf.com
Then have a go with the following code:

```
String input = "<html>\n" +
            "<head><title>Test</title></head>\n" +
            "<body style=\"font-family: FreeSans;\">\n" +
            "<h1>Test</h1>\n" +
            "<br />\n" +
            "<p>Hello World</p>\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";

HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(input, new File("somewhere.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something called avoid page break inside some certain html tag(s), e.g.

```
    @media print
    {
        .no-page-break {
            page-break-inside : avoid;
            -fs-keep-with-inline : keep;
            -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
        }
    }

    <html>
        ...
        <img class="no-page-break" src="...."/>
        ...
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a little hack for this, just put your `<img>` in a `<p>` tag:

```
<html>
    ...
    <p><img class="" src="...."/></p>
    ...
</html>
```